# Java applet/Firefox incompatibility problem

Tags: java, firefox, macos, applet, incompatibility

I've written [a Java applet](http://www.automatous-monk.com/bluepoles/BluePoles.htm).  A user reports that he tried to run it in Firefox 3.0.3 on OS X 10.5.5 but no go. It wants him to download a plug-in, but when he tells it to install missing plug-ins it can't find the appropriate installer...

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get java from Apple, not Sun. Here's a link for it on the [download page](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/apple/application_updates/javaformacosx105update2.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had to make a change in my HTML.  I had to change:

```
<param name = "type" value = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6">
```

to

```
<param name = "type" value = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.5">
```

and

```
type = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" \
```

to

```
type = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.5" \
```

Comment: This will also cause windows users to load the applet in 1.5 JRE instead of 1.6 JRE (if they have both installed).